# rules/attr in jQuery validation

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add custom validation to a dynamically created control. Can I use .attr() to set a rule for a control?

```
$.fn.addValidationExpression = function(field) {

    if (field.ValidationExpression != null) {

        $("#fld"+getFieldIdSuffix(field)).attr("validateExpression", field.ValidationExpression);

    }

    return this;
}
```

What I am trying to avoid is having to do something like this:

```
$("#TestForm").validate(
        {
            rules: 
            {
                someControl: 
                {
                    validateExpression: true
                },
                someOtherControl: 
                {
                    validateExpression: true
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use the [data](http://docs.jquery.com/Data)() option of jquery

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a this.each() in your $ extension as well

Comment: I have it called in a this.each() which adds the controls.